# How to avoid NullPointerException in ArrayList with 2 threads

Tags: java, android, arraylist, thread-synchronization

I'm creating an Android game and I encountered a problem. I have 2 threads: OpenGL thread and game loop. I use ArrayLists to store my renderable objects and here's the problem. Sometimes I need to delete these objects in game thread and sometimes it causes OpenGL thread to get NullPointerException because, as I understand, it goes through the collection and suddenly an element gets deleted. I think I should let OpenGL thread delete objects but is there any other solution and what if game loop will start to get null elements? Maybe I can make synchronize threads somehow though I still don't understand how "synchronized" works. Thanks.

Will this help? And should I put it everwhere I do something with my ArrayList?

```
synchronized (arrayListName) 
{ 
    arrayListName.remove(object); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I still don't understand how "synchronized" works

That is something you will need to remedy. The concurrency constructs within Java including `synchronized` are fundamental concepts. I would recommend picking `Effective Java, 2nd ed.`

> [http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-Edition-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)

One basic idea is that if you have an atomic operation where one thread reads a list item, then the other thread reads the list item, you need to lock that with a binary semaphore - the simplest way of which is to use the Java synchronized construct.

A less naive approach might be to have thread one pull the value from the list, do what it needs to do, then "pass" the value to thread 2, for example, by adding the item to a queue owned by thread 2.

Describing the "right" solution for your application is almost impossible without intimately knowing the code. I'm just making wild guesses.

Comment: no, i doubt it. exclusive access isn't your problem ... your problem that there's some logical block of code that needs to see the array in a consistent state. you would need to synchronize that logical block of code.

Comment: Okay thank you. I will try to find some solution. Queue sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Jeffery's answer is correct but to sum up what the book will say:

"Use `java.util.concurrent` whenever needed."  (paraphrasing)

Basically, don't re-create the wheel.  The `java.util.concurrent` package is a collection of very well optimized thread safe classes like the `ConcurrentHashMap`

Have a look at this related StackOverflow question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395903/why-is-there-not-concurrent-arraylist-in-java-util-concurrent-package

Further reading:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-5things4/index.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html